# Find a caret ^ character in a string with Javascript match

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

Will the `match` method in Javascript find a ^ caret character?

This is not working for me.

```
var theString = '^A^B^C^D';
var theMatch = theString.match(/^/g);
```

The ASCII code for the caret is 94.  Can I match it by the ASCII code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^` is a special character. You must escape it:

```
var theMatch = theString.match(/\^/g);
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement @syntax excellent response. Please note that some characters are like "reserved keywords" in Regular expressions and any time you need to use them you will have to use `\` followed by the character some other examples are `\. \$ \[ \(` and many others.

If need some additional help with regular expression I would like to recommend you a site that does an excellent job reading at your regular expression and this can help you understand them better:

http://regex101.com/